# アラートされません！

Tags: javascript, html

sublime textでアラートを出すプログラムを書きました。
[HTML]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="index" href="index.html">
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
    <input type="button" value="　button" onclick="milk">
</body>
</html>
```

[js]

```
var milk = alert("test now");
```

です。
consoleの部分で
Uncaught ReferenceError: milk is not defined
と出たのですが、どこが間違っているのかわかりません。
教えてください！

・追記
Tetsuya.cさんの方法でやったらアラートが出ました！ありがとうございます。
しかし、今度は
GET file:///C:/Users/Mei/Desktop/testfile2/style.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
というのが出たのですが、これはｃｓｓを入力したら改善されるものですか？

Answer (score -2, accepted):

戻り値が必要であればconfirmで、そもそも呼ばれないのであればlinkにjsを追加してみてください。

Answer (score 3):

エラーメッセージ通り、milkが定義されていません。

javascriptとして関数呼び出しを処理の記述にします。
onclick="milk()"

さらに、jsの実装が不十分

var milk = function() { alert("test now"); }
とか、関数としての定義が必要かと。